# Does ThreadLocal clear values created for already finished threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Does ThreadLocal automatically clear values created for already finished threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the variables are made available for Garbage collections but only if there are no other references to those values (held by some other thread). But when you say a thread is finished, it shouldn't be like a pooled threads. Pooled threads should clear their own variables before they are put back to pool.